Adding second set of points to pairs2 plots
I’m hoping that there is a simple answer to this question - is there a way to plot a second set of points on top of pairs2 plots, from a second dataframe?
This question was somewhat answered here using the pairs function and kmeans for defining centerpoints, but I am attempting to do the same thing using the pairs2 function (I have 8 variables that I am posing against each other, showing part of 4 here for simplicity) and pre-defined centerpoints (contained in a second dataframe that has many less rows than the dataframe with the initial variables) that will change based on the two variables that are used in each plot.
df1 <- data.frame(
  TM = c(25.1889,24.1304,24.0604,23.9402,23.7745,23.6654,23.6645,22.8439,21.3716,21.4657,21.2049,17.3545,17.7282,17.4494,12.2787,12.2857,13.1354,8.2202,8.2664,8.6777,6.2524,6.213,6.2178,5.836,5.6775,5.1592,5.0871,5.169,4.1378,4.1378,4.1187,3.2187,3.2187,3.2308,2.568),
  SAM = c(36.1452,35.8868,35.8872,35.874,35.9173,35.9898,36.0154,36.053,35.8427,35.8532,35.829,35.3498,35.4001,35.3643,34.7479,34.7496,34.8415,34.4096,34.4138,34.4416,34.3268,34.3289,34.329,34.3271,34.3303,34.3649,34.3747,34.3936,34.4629,34.4629,34.4649,34.527,34.527,34.5264,34.5909),
  OY = c(206.2866,212.5171,207.3589,205.7436,202.1023,192.1531,190.6164,179.7472,178.2853,176.2884,176.5031,187.4516,183.8077,184.0845,183.0525,179.0316,179.9783,189.5713,185.268,181.5232,206.1538,201.0054,200.9562,200.0553,193.3422,174.8636,169.43,161.9325,149.089,149.089,150.2571,148.2609,148.2609,149.8462,145.8923),
  SIL = c(0.478441942,0.576011972,0.380745706,0.380736114,0.575939073,0.478281445,0.478272244,0.47814645,1.141410862,0.575593193,0.575563169,1.335656023,1.043229301,1.14068256,4.667007731,4.569575097,3.71251671,1.042085277,9.320365185,8.950634348,13.98250042,14.65426647,14.37189781,17.69141471,20.07645471,31.58209857,33.00297051,35.30033062,57.66252594,57.08823677,57.74992561,78.87097909,78.57900854,78.75430906,99.11314727),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- data.frame(
  params = c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF"),
  Ct = c(4.51,2.2,4.67,1.1,0.89,7.3),
  Sa = c(34.25,34.57,34.67,34.73,34.7,34.6),
  Ph = c(1.2,2.09,3.3,2.76,1.89,1.1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#I am using pairs2 currently as follows to plot the df1 variables against each other:

pairs2(df1[1], df1[c(2,3,4)])

As per the pairs answer linked above, I attempted to use rbind to have these both appear together on the same plot, but I’m thinking that pairs2 acts differently than pairs with this function as I got several errors for extra “,” that I’m not sure actually had anything to do with the function itself.

Where is the pairs2 function from?

Not sure if this answers your question: pairs2 takes 2 data frames and does all combinations of the first on the x-axis with the 2nd on the y-axis: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TeachingDemos/versions/2.13/topics/pairs2.  It’s a base r function as far as I know.

It's not a base R function. That link implies it's from the TeachingDemos package. Are you loading that package in your workspace? Are you sure that's the version you are using?

Ah, gotcha. I’m not always super up to speed on what different packages, etc, mean, sorry about that. I do have TeachingDemos loaded in and it runs just fine for the variables that I have, those plots are great, I’m really just wondering if I can plot a second set of points on top of the plots that I already have
